# IDLE3.6.1 is just running console window but not executing

Tags: python, python-3.6, zelle-graphics

The following code in python graphics of IDLE3.6.1 is not running it is just running console window but not executing:

```
from graphics import*
import time

def moveAll(shapeList,dx,dy):
    for shape in shapeList:
        shape.move(dx,dy)

def moveAllOnline(shapeList,dx,dy,repititions,delay):
    for i in range(repititions):
        moveAll(shapeList,dx,dy)
        time.sleep(delay)

def makeFace(center,win):
    head=Circle(center,25)
    head.setFill("green")
    head.draw(win)
    eye1Center=center.clone()
    eye1Center.move(-10,5)
    eye1=Circle(eye1Center,5)
    eye1.setFill("blue")
    eye1.draw(win)
    eye2End1=eye1Center.clone()
    eye2End1.move(15,0)
    eye2End2=eye2End1.clone()
    eye2End2.move(10,0)
    eye2=Line(eye2End1,eye2End2)
    eye2.setWidth(3)
    eye2.draw(win)
    mouthCorner1=center.clone()
    mouthCorner1.move(-10,-10)
    mouthCorner2=mouthCorner1.clone()
    mouthCorner2.move(20,-5)
    mouth=Oval(mouthcorner1,mouthCorner2)
    mouth.setFill("red")
    mouth.draw(win)
    return [head,eye1,eye2,mouth]

def main():
    winWidth=300
    winHeight=300
    win=GraphWin('Back and forth',winWidth,winHeight)
    win.setCoords(0,0,winWidth,winHeight)
    rect=Rectangle(Point(200,90),Point(220,100))
    rect.setFill("blue")
    rect.draw(win)
    faceList=makeFace(Point(40,100),win)
    faceList2=makeFace(Point(150,125),win)
    stepsAcross=46
    dx=5
    dy=3
    wait=0.05
    for i in range(3):
        makeAllOnline(facelist,dx,0,stepsAcross,wait)
        moveAllOnLine(faceList,-dx,dy,stepsAcross//2,wait)
        moveAllOnLine(faceList,-dx,dy,stepsAcross//2,wait)
    message=Text(Point(winWidth/2,20),'Click here to quit')
    message.draw(win)
    win.getmouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

Comment: Please, correct the formatting of your question

Comment: Reindented code.

Comment: Reindented the reindented code.

Answer (score 0):

I found several problems with your code: even after @phd formatted it per @mkiever's request, these lines were indented one level too many:

```
message=Text(Point(winWidth/2,20),'Click here to quit')
message.draw(win)
win.getmouse()
win.close()
```

They should not be part of the loop.  You also had multiple case-related misspellings in the code:

```
makeAllOnline -> moveAllOnLine
moveAllOnline -> moveAllOnLine
mouthcorner1 -> mouthCorner1
facelist -> faceList
```

I've reworked it to make it readable and runnable from the Python console:

```
import time
from graphics import *

def moveAll(shapeList, dx, dy):
    for shape in shapeList:
        shape.move(dx, dy)

def moveAllOnLine(shapeList, dx, dy, repetitions, delay):
    for _ in range(repetitions):
        moveAll(shapeList, dx, dy)
        time.sleep(delay)

def makeFace(center, win):
    head = Circle(center, 25)
    head.setFill('green')
    head.draw(win)

    eye1Center = center.clone()
    eye1Center.move(-10, 5)
    eye1 = Circle(eye1Center, 5)
    eye1.setFill('blue')
    eye1.draw(win)

    eye2End1 = eye1Center.clone()
    eye2End1.move(15, 0)
    eye2End2 = eye2End1.clone()
    eye2End2.move(10, 0)
    eye2 = Line(eye2End1, eye2End2)
    eye2.setWidth(3)
    eye2.draw(win)

    mouthCorner1 = center.clone()
    mouthCorner1.move(-10, -10)
    mouthCorner2 = mouthCorner1.clone()
    mouthCorner2.move(20, -5)
    mouth = Oval(mouthCorner1, mouthCorner2)
    mouth.setFill('red')
    mouth.draw(win)

    return [head, eye1, eye2, mouth]

def main():
    winWidth, winHeight = 300, 300
    win = GraphWin('Back and forth', winWidth, winHeight)
    win.setCoords(0, 0, winWidth, winHeight)

    rect = Rectangle(Point(200, 90), Point(220, 100))
    rect.setFill('blue')
    rect.draw(win)

    faceList = makeFace(Point(40, 100), win)

    stepsAcross = 46
    dx, dy = 5, 3
    wait = 0.05

    for _ in range(3):
        moveAllOnLine(faceList, dx, 0, stepsAcross, wait)
        moveAllOnLine(faceList, -dx, dy, stepsAcross // 2, wait)
        moveAllOnLine(faceList, -dx, dy, stepsAcross // 2, wait)

    message = Text(Point(winWidth / 2, 20), 'Click here to quit')
    message.draw(win)

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

As far as IDLE, my experience was that the graphics window came up behind the console window so you need to move the windows as it starts up. Whether it does what you intended, I've no idea:

[image]